# Regular expression woes

Tags: java, c++, expression, newline

I have the following data of which i would like to convert it to regular expression.

PALMKERNEL OIL Mal/Indo dlrs tonne cif Rotterdam

Dec15/Jan16      890.00

Jan16/Feb16      900.00   +10.00

My code below doesn't seem to work. Firstly how do I determine that after the 890, there could be either nothing or there could be a +10.00 or any number in that format? I tried to use ?: but sometimes it will totally ignore the month information which i am trying to capture..In this case i do not want to capture the +10.00 or any characters after the price of 890 or 900.

(PALMKERNEL OIL Mal\b)/(Indo dlrs tonne cif Rotterdam\b)\s*([^\s]+)\s*(\d*.?\d*)\s*([^\s]+|[+\d*.?\d*])\s*(\d*.?\d*)\s*([^\s]+|(?:[+\d*.?\d*]))

Comment: Well as the saying goes, [you have one problem so you use regular expressions, and now you have *two* problems](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems). ;)

Comment: Which language are you using C++ or Java?  Please remove at least one of  the tags

Comment: The  \b in `Mal\b/` is redundant. - Instead of `[ ^\s]+` use the simple `\S+`.  - A literal dot must be written as `\.` - The construct  `[+\d*.?\d*]` doesn't match something like `+10.00` -  it matches a single character that is either a digit (\d), an asterisk (*), a plus (+), a period (.) because  `[...]` matches a any character from the set (!) between the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

For the part with the dates and prices, this regular expression handles the two variants in your sample string.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( 
     "\\w{3}\\d{1,2}/\\w{3}\\d{1,2}" +
     "\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d\\d)(\\s+\\+\\d+\\.\\d\\d)?" );
String s1 = "Dec15/Jan16 890.00";
String s2 = "Jan16/Feb16 900.00 +10.00";
Matcher m1 = pat.matcher( s1 ); 
if( m1.matches() )
  System.out.println("m1 " + m1.group(1) + ":" + m1.group(2) );
Matcher m2 = pat.matcher( s2 ); 
if( m2.matches() )
  System.out.println("m2 " + m2.group(1) + ":" + m2.group(2) );
```

Output:

```
m1 890.00:null
m2 900.00: +10.00
```

There's not enough information - so I don't know about a third alternative in /+10.00/?.